# a model failed to load due to an error and AppRegistry.registerComponent wasnt called REACT-NATIVE

Tags: javascript, react-native

im building a music player, using `react-native-track-playe v1.2.3`, so i needed so functions that are in the `v2` so i installed it `npm i react-native-track-player@2.0.0-rc13`, in my project the package.json `` react-native`track-player `` is already in v2, but when i reload the project this error came out:

[image]

this is my index:

```
import {AppRegistry} from "react-native";
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from "./app.json";
import TrackPlayer from "react-native-track-player";

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
TrackPlayer.registerPlaybackService( () => require("./services/Services.js"));
```

and heres the app:

```
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';
import * as React from 'react';
import Tab_Navigator from "./routes/Tab_Navigator";
import { AppProvider } from "./context/AppProvider";

console.reportErrorsAsExceptions = false;

export default class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <AppProvider>
          <Tab_Navigator></Tab_Navigator>
        </AppProvider>
      </>
    );
  } 
}

registerRootComponent(App);
```

eveything is the same before i update the package, didnt touch anything, how can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
import {AppRegistry} from "react-native";
import App from './App';

AppRegistry.registerComponent("AppName", () => App);
```

Comment: @AC_Valhalla start node server again reset cache and clean build then try